# Proof that median of an array is the number that minimizes the sum of manhattan distance to all points

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

Given a sorted array A, the problem is to find a number that minimizes the sum of Manhattan distance to the numbers in the array. I found that the median of A is the solution, but was not able to come up for a proof or explanation for the same ( i.e why its not mean).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270/the-median-minimizes-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations

Comment: Also see this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7155426/948794

Comment: What does "Manhattan distance" mean in this context? What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Manhattan distance always means L1 distance.

Comment: There can easily be more than one "number that minimizes the sum of manhattan distance to all points". ​ For example, consider the sorted array [0,4]. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I have tried to come up with expressions for manhattan distance assuming the minimizing point to be mean and median. Currently, I am not able to compare the two expressions ( I know this is a naive, as I directly started with mean and median). Anyways, the first comment helped.

Comment: 1. I don't understand what Manhattan distance means in this context.  I'm used to the Manhattan distance providing a way to compute the distance between two vectors.  Here you have a vector and a number.  I don't know what it means to talk about the Manhattan distance between a number and an array/vector.  Can you edit the question to provide a self-contained description of what that means?  2. What have you tried?  Where did you get the stuck?  Did you try proving it for arrays of length 2 or arrays of length 3?

Answer (score 1):

marks the set of numbers $$P=\{P_1,P_2,P_3, \ldots ,P_n\}$$

need to find number $X$:

$|P_1-X|+|P_2-X|+\ldots+|P_n-X|=D$, which minimizes $D$.

the fact that X is the median can be shown using induction on the number of numbers n in $P$.

Base: $n=1$: trivial to see that the median is $P_1$ and $|P_1-P_1|=D=0$ is minimal ($D>=0$).

now suppose that this holds for all $P$ of size $|P|=n$, we need to show that this holds for $|P|=n+1$.

In other words:

given that $$|P_1-X|+|P_2-X|+\ldots+|P_n-X|=D$$ is minimal when $X=P_m$ is the median of $P=\{P_1,P_2,P_3, \ldots ,P_n\}$ show that $|P_1-X|+|P_2-X|+\ldots+|P_n-X|=D$ is minimal when $X=P_m'$ is the median of $P=\{P_1,P_2,P_3, \ldots ,P_{n+1}\}$.
notice that there are two cases $m'=m+1$ ($n$ is even) or $m'=m$ ($n$ is odd).

I suggest drawing a simple example using $n=3$ and $n+1=4$ on an axis. Can you see why this must hold?

Comment: I suggest learning LaTeX and using it to enhance the way your answers look.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?